# Member function that alters state of object of other class

Tags: c++11, vector

I have a very quick question. I stumbled upon a (weird) error in my code. I have a class that has a container (vector) of actual objects of another class in it. In a function I try to update the state of the objects, which should not be a problem. And locally, inside the function, it works fine. The objects are altered. But when I exit the member function (or just the for loop!) and read the objects' state I see that nothing has actually changed! Very strange. Do you guys know why? I did not use pointers to the objects in the vector, is that the issue maybe? Here's snippets of the code that are important:

```
template<typename T>
class Particle
{
    private:
        std::array<T,3> position;
        std::array<T,3> nextPosition;
        //[...]
    public:
        void SetPosition(T rx, T ry, T rz);
        void SetPosition(std::array<T,3> update);
        void SetNextPosition(std::array<T,3> update);
        std::array<T,3> GetNextPosition();
        std::array<T,3> GetPosition();
        //[...]
};
template <typename T>
void Particle<T>::SetPosition(std::array<T,3> update){this->position = update;}
template <typename T>
std::array<T,3> Particle<T>::GetPosition(){return this->position;}
template <typename T>
std::array<T,3> Particle<T>::GetNextPosition(){return this->nextPosition;}
```

The Box class has `std::vector<Particle<T> > pList;` as private variable which I correctly loaded with particles. Everything goes well and I can change the state until I call the following function that should shift the position state of the particle (but it doesn't! when outside the for loop). So to make it clear; when I print out the state of the objects inside the for loop it seems to work just fine. But when the for loop is finished/terminated the objects have not changed at all!

```
template <typename T>
void Box<T>::Simulate(unsigned int timestep, T verletstep){
     //[...]
     for(auto x:this->pList) x.SetPosition( x.GetNextPosition() );
     //[...]
}
```

Can anyone see why?
Appreciate it!

Comment: _"I see that nothing has actually changed!"_ Can you demonstrate that in future? We like to see _evidence_ and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making copies everywhere, not least of all here:

```
for(auto x:this->pList)
```

Start introducing the use of *references*; for example:

```
for(auto& x:this->pList)
```

Comment: thank you! That was actually the case. But I do not understand why. Yes I was making copies everywhere, but in this case it shouldn't matter right? I access the objects in the vector, and it doesn't make a copy and stores that in x in the for loop right? I actually get the object stored at that element in the vector.

Comment: @LoekJanssen: Why do you say that? In general you get copies of things until you ask not to. `int x = 42; int y = x;` now you have a _copy_ of `x`. It's precisely the same thing here.